# Adium: Show Invisible, but online, contacts in buddy list?

Tags: plugins, chat, xmpp, adium

Is there a setting, plugin or extra that will make my Adium contact list include users who are online but set to "invisible"?

Answer (score 4):

Never having heard about *Adium*, i'm going to answer your question and say, "*No*". The contact is invisible so you can't see them.

If you're able to see people who have set themselves to invisible, then it's going to be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

No.

When a user sets himself as "invisible", the IM server reports his status as "offline" to you, exactly as if the user was logged out. **That's the whole point of "Invisible" mode.**

Answer (score 1):

Adium does show invisible, but online contacts. Atleast for jabber accounts. I'm talking about version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. temporarily turn off View→Hide Certain Contacts ( ⇧⌘H )
2. single-click on the contact to select it
3. choose Get Info from the Contact menu ( ⌘I )
4. go to the fourth tab: ⚙  ("Advanced Settings")
5. check the box for ☑ Always show this contact
6. if desired, reactivate Hide Certain Contacts ( ⇧⌘H )

Comment: Note that this does what it says on the tin, showing them whether online or not—invisible is invisible—but this setting lets one easily initiate a new chat. Also; yes its a five-year question necro, but this question was first in my search results, so no ragrets.